# Error en condicional con estamento in: "requires string as left operand, not set"

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, loops

Estoy creando un bucle que va a iterar sobre una lista de cadenas dadas. Para ello he creado un conjunto de datos sobre los que estableceré mis condiciones dentro del bucle.

Pero creo que estoy haciendo algo mal porque en la shell de Python me salta el siguiente error:

> "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not set".

No sé si será un problema de los conjuntos creados (igual se deben formar con el `set()`), pero creo que en teoría debería funcionar con los conjuntos que he creado.

```
Result=[]
Dna_bases = {'a', 't', 'c', 'g'}
Rna_bases = {'a', 'u', 'c', 'g'}

chain_list= ['ttgaatgccttacaact', 'aucgcgauacgacgu', 'aaacggacgacgxxn4']
for i in chain_list:
if Dna_bases in i and 'u' not in i:
    print(Result.append('DNA'))
elif Rna_bases in i and 't' not in i:
    print(Result.append('RNA'))
else:
    print(Result.append('UKN'))

print ('Result =', Result)
```

El resultado debería ser:

> Resultado = ['DNA', 'RNA', 'UKN']

Answer (score 1):

Con `if Dna_bases in i` Estas 'preguntando' si un conjunto (`set`) esta dentro de una cadena ("str"). Se espera que preguntes si una cadena está contenida en la otra, que **los objetos a ambos lados del `in`  sean del mismo tipo**.

De todas formas no probarías nada con esa lógica, si el conjunto está en la cadena no significa que la cadena no contenga bases que no están en el conjunto y diferentes de `u` o `t` respectivamente.

Lo que quieres hacer es ver si todas las bases de una cadena forman parte de uno de los conjuntos o de ninguno. Para ello simplemente crea un conjunto con las bases de cada cadena y realizas la diferencia de conjuntos con `Dna_bases` y `Rna_bases`.

Cuando le pasas una cadena al constructor de `set` se crea un conjunto con todos los caracteres contenidos en la cadena sin repeticiones. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> c = aucgcgauacgacgu
>>> set_c = set(c)
>>> set_c
{'c', 'u', 'a', 'g'}
```

Si realizas la diferencia de conjuntos con otro conjunto obtendrás los caracteres que están en el primero pero no en el segundo:

```
>>> {'c', 'u', 'a', 'g'} - {'a', 'u', 'c', 'g'}
set()
>>> {'c', 'u', 'a', 'g'} - {'a', 't', 'c', 'g'}
set('u')
```

Esto podemos aplicarlo a nuestro problema ya que **si todas las bases de la cadena están en el conjunto se retornará un conjunto vacío.**

Tu código sería algo así:

```
Result=[]
Dna_bases = {'a', 't', 'c', 'g'}
Rna_bases = {'a', 'u', 'c', 'g'}

chain_list= ['ttgaatgccttacaact', 'aucgcgauacgacgu', 'aaacggacgacgxxn4']
for i in chain_list:
    chain_set = set(i) 
    if not chain_set - Dna_bases:
        Result.append('DNA')
    elif not chain_set - Rna_bases:
        Result.append('RNA')
    else:
        Result.append('UKN')

print ('Result =', Result)
```

**Salida:**

> Result = ['DNA', 'RNA', 'UKN']

Hay que tener en cuenta que una supuesta cadena como "acagcc" será retornada como ADN aunque podría ser también ARN. Si esta posibilidad existe podrias hacer algo como:

```
Result=[]
Dna_bases = {'a', 't', 'c', 'g'}
Rna_bases = {'a', 'u', 'c', 'g'}

chain_list= ["acagcc", 'ttgaatgccttacaact', 'aucgcgauacgacgu', 'aaacggacgacgxxn4']
for i in chain_list:
    chain_set = set(i) 
    if (not chain_set - Dna_bases) and (not chain_set - Rna_bases):
        Result.append('DNA/RNA')
    elif not chain_set - Dna_bases:
        Result.append('DNA')
    elif not chain_set - Rna_bases:
        Result.append('RNA')
    else:
        Result.append('UKN')

print ('Result =', Result)
```

**Salida:**

> Result = ['DNA/RNA', 'DNA', 'RNA', 'UKN']

Answer (score 1):

En la respuesta de @FJSevilla te explica porqué falla y un modo de arreglarlo.

Al hacer `Dna_bases in i` estás chequeando si en `i` está incluido el *set* `Dna_bases`. Como ambos objetos no son comparables, da error.

Antes de seguir, voy a cambiar tu código inicial para que sea más legible y pythónico:

```
result=[]
DNA_BASES = {'a', 't', 'c', 'g'}
RNA_BASES = {'a', 'u', 'c', 'g'}

chain_list= ['ttgaatgccttacaact', 'aucgcgauacgacgu', 'aaacggacgacgxxn4']

for dna in chain_list:
    if DNA_BASES in dna and 'u' not in dna:
        print(result.append('DNA'))
    elif RNA_BASES in dna and 't' not in dna:
        print(result.append('RNA'))
    else:
        print(result.append('UKN'))

print ('Result =', result)
```

En realidad, lo que necesitas es comprobar si cada carácter de una cadena pertenece a un conjunto:

```
"a" in DNA_BASES
```

Para iterar toda la cadena, podemos usar `all` en la siguiente expresión idiomática:

```
all(x in DNA_BASES for x in dna)
```

Para que `all` devuelva `True`, todas las letras de `dna` tienen que estar en `DNA_BASES`. No es necesario comprobar que no esté la letra `u`.

Se puede hacer mucho mejor utilizando *conjuntos* (`sets`):

```
set(dna) <= DNA_BASES
```

Buscamos que los aminoácidos de `dna` estén incluidos en `DNA_BASES`, por éso se usa `<=`.

Lo mismo sería para `RNA_BASES`. Si creamos una función de comprobación, el código resultante nos quedaría así:

```
DNA_BASES = {'a', 't', 'c', 'g'}
RNA_BASES = {'a', 'u', 'c', 'g'}

chain_list= ['ttgaatgccttacaact', 'aucgcgauacgacgu', 'aaacggacgacgxxn4']

def check(seq):
    amins = set(seq)
    return 'DNA' if amins <= DNA_BASES \
      else 'RNA' if amins <= RNA_BASES \
      else 'UKN'

result = [check(dna) for dna in chain_list]
```